# Getting values from span tags with slider options through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have the following code with slider options.

```
    <div class="time-filter">
        <div id="weekline"></div>
        <div id="time-range">
            <p><span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">12:00 PM</span>

            </p>
            <div class="sliders_step1">
                <div id="slider-range"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to get the changed values of the "slider-time" and "slider-time2" span tags after a certain interval of time e.g. when the time changed in the span tags i need to get the changed time value from both the span tags after 3 Seconds with jQuery.
How i will do it?

[image]

I have tried the following code:

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$(".slider-time").on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
    var timeHandler = setInterval(function(){
        alert($(".slider-time").html()+' x '+$(".slider-time2").html());
        },4000);
        clearInterval(timeHandler);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Share your attempt

Comment: Have you tried `change` event handler? `$(".slider-time").on("change",function(){ // code });` instead of `DOMSubtreeModified`

Comment: Yes i have test with change but change event is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

try with this below code, it may help you...

```js
$('#time-range').on("DOMSubtreeModified propertychange", function() {
var getSlidTime1 = $(".slider-time").html();
var getSlidTime2 = $(".slider-time2").html();
setInterval(function(){ alert(getSlidTime1+' - '+getSlidTime2); }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-filter">
  <div id="weekline"></div>
  <div id="time-range">
    <p><span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">12:00 PM</span>

    </p>
    <div class="sliders_step1">
      <div id="slider-range"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what if the values for the "slider-time" with slider?